# vb.net sort listview followed by coloring alternate rows not working

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listview, colors, alternate

I can get my listview to alternate colored rows or sort but not both.  The sorting does not appear to be complete before the alternate rows are colored leading to the row's coloring being jumbled up, but sorted in the listview. How can I make sure the listviewItemSorter is done before calling my function SetAlternateColors?

```
    lvGedcom.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewComparer(0, SortOrder.Ascending)
    lvGedcom.Sort()
    InfraT.SetAlternateColor(lvGedcom)
```

I tried a sleep after the sort to no avail...

```
    Public Shared Sub SetAlternateColor(sender As Object)
    'Set color striping on listview
    For i As Integer = 0 To sender.Items.Count - 1 Step 2
        sender.Items(i).BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
        If i < sender.items.Count - 1 Then
            sender.Items(i + 1).BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Custom sorter from: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_listview_sort_clicked_column.html

```
Class ListViewComparer
Implements IComparer

Private m_ColumnNumber As Integer
Private m_SortOrder As SortOrder

Public Sub New(ByVal column_number As Integer, ByVal _
    sort_order As SortOrder)
    m_ColumnNumber = column_number
    m_SortOrder = sort_order
End Sub

' Compare the items in the appropriate column
' for objects x and y.
Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As _
    Object) As Integer Implements _
    System.Collections.IComparer.Compare
    Dim item_x As ListViewItem = DirectCast(x,
        ListViewItem)
    Dim item_y As ListViewItem = DirectCast(y,
        ListViewItem)

    ' Get the sub-item values.
    Dim string_x As String
    If item_x.SubItems.Count <= m_ColumnNumber Then
        string_x = ""
    Else
        string_x = item_x.SubItems(m_ColumnNumber).Text
    End If

    Dim string_y As String
    If item_y.SubItems.Count <= m_ColumnNumber Then
        string_y = ""
    Else
        string_y = item_y.SubItems(m_ColumnNumber).Text
    End If

    ' Compare them.
    If m_SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending Then
        If IsNumeric(string_x) And IsNumeric(string_y) _
            Then
            Return Val(string_x).CompareTo(Val(string_y))
        ElseIf IsDate(string_x) And IsDate(string_y) _
            Then
            Return DateTime.Parse(string_x).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(string_y))
        Else
            Return String.Compare(string_x, string_y)
        End If
    Else
        If IsNumeric(string_x) And IsNumeric(string_y) _
            Then
            Return Val(string_y).CompareTo(Val(string_x))
        ElseIf IsDate(string_x) And IsDate(string_y) _
            Then
            Return DateTime.Parse(string_y).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(string_x))
        Else
            Return String.Compare(string_y, string_x)
        End If
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried to call `Refresh()` after `Sort()` (it shouldn't be needed, but try it anyway). Change `sender As Object` into `sender As ListView`. With `SortOrder.Ascending` are you returning `-string.Compare()` or setting the `Sorting` property? Can you show your custom comparer? Btw, this is clearly a WinForms' ListView, but you should tag your question anyway.

Comment: Note that setting the `Sorting` property with a value that is not `SortOrder.None`, causes the Control to recreate the handle.

Comment: Jimi - Tried refresh to no avail.  the custom comparer I got here - http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_listview_sort_clicked_column.html.  The Sorting properly is set to SortOrder.None.  I tried without a custom comparer and just setting to the sorting properly to acsending but that gave the same result.

Comment: Post here what you're actually using in your code, plus some context related to when/where/how this code is used (what activates the sorting operation of your ListView). The use of threads etc. Possibly, try with a Project built from scratch and sort a ListView with standard options. See if you can replicated the problem (I cannot). -- I'll take a look at your comparer, to see if there's something *weird*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what activates the sorting operation.  Doesn't that happen as items are added to the listview?  I create an array and add it to the listview   lvGedcom.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(arr))   then call the three lines of code above

Comment: Oh, I have another form with a button that I click which opens a file dialog to find the file I want, then opens a new form with the lvGedcom on it that should load, sort and alternate lines. All the new form does is parse the file and load the listview so far.

Comment: All right, but **where** is this done? In the Form's Constructor? in the `Load` event `OnLoad` method? `Shown` event `OnShown` method? Other? Are you using Threads or Tasks? -- I just tested your code - all of it - the ListView is sorting and alternating colors as it's supposed to. I used a ListView with pre-built ListViewItems (+ 3 SubItems) in `Details` View

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221391/discussion-between-sharon-dankwardt-and-jimi).

Answer (score 0):

the calls to populate and sort the listview needed to come from a load event rather then from new and then it worked like a charm.  Thanks to Jimi for the assist.